# Storybook manager.ts file triggers compilation errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I do not understand why it happens but if I have simple manager.ts file like

```
import { addons } from "@storybook/addons";
import { create } from "@storybook/theming";

import { palette } from "../theme/src"; // @ds/theme

const theme = create({
    base: "light",
    colorPrimary: palette.magenta01,
    colorSecondary: palette.magenta01,
});

addons.setConfig({
    theme,
});
```

and use alias path instead of relative path in import, it throws me an error . In preview.ts and any other storybook's config files importing using this alias works perfectly fine. It also works if I remove manager.ts at all

```
ERROR in ./libs/design-system/.storybook/manager.ts 3:0-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ds/theme' in '/Users/x/libs/design-system/.storybook'
resolve '@ds/theme' in '/Users/x/libs/design-system/.storybook'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/x/package.json (relative path: ./libs/design-system/.storybook)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
```

Answer (score 1):

In 6.x and earlier, Storybook's "manager" UI was built using Webpack, so it might have been possible to configure that webpack process to respect aliases. In 7.0, its using esbuild instead, and it is no longer configurable. The new setup is faster and simpler, but you'll need to prebundle your addon if you want to use advanced features. You'll need to precompile/pretranspile code if using aliasses.

https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/20582